# Creating multiple custom check-in policies in TFS 2010/2013

Tags: checkin

I have been asked to refactor an existing set of custom check-in policies for TFS 2010. The current implementation has a separate project for each check-in policy. Someone suggested these all be in one project. I am reading documentation on creating custom check-in policies but everyone I've seen so far gives an example of writing a single custom check-in policy.

Can you and would you combine them into one project or do they have to be separate like the current implementation?

Thanks!